# iOS: Deleting an In App Purchase Subscription Auto Renewal product

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have an app with an IAP which is an auto renewable subscription product.
I was just asked to remove this product all together from iTunes Connect.
I am wondering what would happen to my users who are already enrolled to this product once their current subscription period ends.

I have noticed that once I register to an In App Purchase callback at the beginning of the app, Apple initiate a test to renew the product and notify my functions. Does anybody know if now that the product would be missing all of my subscribed users would start getting error popups when they open the app or will they simply continue without the product once the current period ends?

Thanks

Roi

Comment: Did you ever figure out what happened here?

Comment: I have the same question, any idea?